# jQuery Mobile dynamic listview

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, rss

I have create a jquery mobile phonegap mobile application of showing the technologies news from an rss feed. On a web navigator it work correctly but when i create the .apk file the title and the content not showing on the list

[My app on web navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVJTT.png)

[My app .apk installed on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5So7W.jpg)

the code of the app :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Technologia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            // ISCPA added search filter, home icon, updated CDN-Hosted links
// forked from sumukh1's "forked: RSS Reader with jQuery Mobile" http://jsdo.it/sumukh1/4Ton
            /* configuration */
            var maxLength = 20;
            /* writing HTML */
            document.write(
                    '<div data-role="page"  id="list">' +
                    '<div data-role="panel" data-theme="b" id="menu" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" >' +
                    '<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="actu.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/actu.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Acualités</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="logiciel.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/logiciel.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Applis,Logiciels</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="jeux.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/jeux.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Jeux</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="pc.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/pc.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> PC Périphériques</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="smartphone.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/mobile.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Smartphone</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="tablette.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/tablet.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Tablette</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="objets.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/objets.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Objets connectés</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="media.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/media.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Culture, médias</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="politique.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/politique.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> Politique, Droits</a></li>' +
                    '<li data-icon="false"><a href="propos.html" rel="external"> <img src="img/propos.png" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none"> À propos</a></li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">' +
                    ' <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#menu" data-display="overlay" data-role="button" data-icon="bars"></a>' +
                    '    <h1>Actualités</h1>' +
                    '  </div>' +
                    '  <div data-role="content">' +
                    '    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Chercher"  data-inset="true" id="articleList">'
                    );
            for (var i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
                document.write(
                        '<li data-icon="false" id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>'
                        );
            }
            document.write(
                    '    </ul>' +
                    '  </div>' +
                    '</div>'
                    );
            for (i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
                document.write(
                        '<div data-role="page" id="article' + i + '">' +
                        '  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">' +
                        '    <a href="#list" data-role="button" data-icon="carat-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-back="true">Home</a>' +
                        '    <h1 id="articleHeader' + i + '">&nbsp;</h1>' +
                        '  </div>' +
                        '  <div data-role="content">' +
                        '    <div id="articleContent' + i + '" class="articleContent"></div>' +
                        '    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">' +
                        '      <a href="#article' + String(i - 1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"' +
                        '        data-inline="true" class="prevButton">Précident</a>' +
                        '      <a href="#article' + String(i + 1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"' +
                        '        data-inline="true" class="nextButton" data-iconpos="right">Suivant</a>' +
                        '    </div>' +
                        '  </div>' +
                        '</div>'
                        );
            }
            /* JSONP */
            $(function () {

                getOnlineFeed('http://www.01net.com/rss/info/flux-rss/flux-toutes-les-actualites/');


            });
            /* functions */
            var listEntries = function (json) {
                if (!json.responseData.feed.entries)
                    return false;

                var articleLength = json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
                articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
                for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength; i++) {
                    var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i - 1];

                    var des = entry.content;
                    var ctn;
                    var lnn = des.length;
                    var fn = des.indexOf("<img");
                    ctn = des.substr(0, fn - 1);

                    var start = des.indexOf("src=");
                    var end = lnn - (start + 5);

                    var imgs = des.substr(start + 5, end - 2);

                    var date = entry.publishedDate.substr(5, 11);

                    var liste = {
                        Jan: 'Janvier',
                        Feb: 'Février',
                        Mar: 'Mars',
                        Apr: 'Avril',
                        May: 'Mai',
                        Jun: 'juin',
                        Jul: 'juillet',
                        Aug: 'août',
                        Sep: 'septembre',
                        Oct: 'octobre',
                        Nov: 'novembre',
                        Dec: 'décembre'
                    };

                    var jour = date.substr(0, 2);
                    var bl = date.indexOf(" 2");
                    var xs = date.substr(3, 3);
                    var annes = date.substr(bl, date.length);
                    var mois = liste[xs];

                    $('#link' + i).html("<h5>" + entry.title + "</h5>" + "<p>" + ctn + "</p>");
                    $('#articleHeader' + i).text("Actualités");
                    $('#openButton' + i).attr('href', entry.link);
                    $('#articleContent' + i).append("<strong>" + entry.title + "</strong><br><br>" + ctn);
                    $('#articleContent' + i).append('<img class="pic" src="' + imgs + '">');
                    $('#articleContent' + i).append("<br> Date de publication : " + jour + " " + mois + annes);
                    $('#articleContent' + i).append('<br><br><center><a class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left" href="' + entry.link + '" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" >Voir plus</a></center>');



                }
                $('#article1 .prevButton').remove();
                $('#article' + articleLength + ' .nextButton').remove();
                if (articleLength < maxLength) {
                    for (i = articleLength + 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
                        $('#list' + i).remove();
                        $('#article' + i).remove();
                    }
                }
            };
            var getOnlineFeed = function (url) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?callback=listEntries&hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q='
                        + encodeURIComponent(url)
                        + '&v=1.0&num=' + maxLength);
                script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
            };
            var getOfflineFeed = function (url) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.setAttribute('src', url);
                script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
            };
            $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

                window.open(targetURL, "_system");
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it cant connect to your API, any chance you haven't whitelist you remote connections?

If not download the [cordova whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and add the following to your `config.xml`

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```